# Selecionar automaticamente campo

Tags: html, vb.net

Pessoal tenho um campo:

[image: http://prntscr.com/6ynejl]

Coloquei pra preencher automaticamente no `VB`:

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").GetElementsByName("NW_State").Item(0).SetAttribute("value", "AK")
```

Mas não vai de jeito nenhum, já tentei de várias formas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode recuperar os itens filhos do `select` e iterar por eles, selecionando aquele que tem o texto procurado:

```
Dim htmlElm As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").GetElementsByName("NW_State").Item(0)
    For Each item As HtmlElement In htmlElm.Children
        If (item.InnerHtml = "AZ") Then
            item.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
        Else
            item.SetAttribute("selected", String.Empty)
        End If
    Next
```